# How to make a droplist expand on hover instead of on click?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I have a droplist on my web page that expands when clicking the "Import (CSV)" button. I would like the droplist to expand when hovering over the button instead of clicking it.

I have tried using the "mouseover" and "mouseenter" events, but I can't seem to get them to work properly. Below is the HTML and CSS code that I have so far:

```css
[type="checkbox"]:checked,
[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked){
  position: absolute;
  left: -9999px;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown:checked + label,
.dropdown:not(:checked) + label{
  line-height: 2;
  height: 44px;
  border-radius: 4px;
  width: 190px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  display: inline-flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -moz-justify-content: center;
  -ms-justify-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  background-color: #a77bca;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown:not(:checked):hover+ label{
  background-color:#33174a
}
.dropdown:checked + label:before,
.dropdown:not(:checked) + label:before{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  cursor: auto;
  pointer-events: none;
}


.section-dropdown {
  position: absolute;
  padding: 2px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 4px;
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  transform: translateY(20px);
}

.dropdown:checked ~ .section-dropdown{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
  transform: translateY(0);
}


a {
  position: relative;
  color: #535e73;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  padding: 15px 0;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin: 2px 0;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -moz-align-items: center;
  -ms-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
    cursor: pointer;
}

a:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #a77bca;
}

a .uil {
  font-size: 22px;
}
.dropdown-sub:checked + label,
.dropdown-sub:not(:checked) + label{
  position: relative;
  color: #fff;
  transition: all 200ms linear;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-align: left;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
}
.hover-class {
  background-color: #a77bca;
}
.import-button:hover {
  background-color: #666; /* oscurece el fondo del botón */
  color: #fff; /* cambia el color del texto del botón */
}
```

```html
     <div class="sec-center" >
          <input class="dropdown" type="checkbox" id="dropdown" name="dropdown" (click)="abrir()">
          <label class="for-dropdown " for="dropdown">Importar (CSV)</label>
          <div class="section-dropdown" *ngIf="cerrarDropdown">
            <a (click)="openImportOrders()">Importar órdenes (CSV)<i class="uil uil-arrow-right"></i> </a>
            <input class="dropdown-sub" type="checkbox" id="dropdown-sub" name="dropdown-sub" />
        
            <a (click)="openImport()">Importar citas (CSV)<i class="uil uil-arrow-right"> </i> </a>
            <input class="dropdown-sub" type="checkbox" id="dropdown-sub" name="dropdown-sub" />
        
            <a (click)="cancelOrdersByCsv()" >
              Cancelar órdenes(CSV) <i class="uil uil-arrow-right"> </i> </a>
            <input class="dropdown-sub" type="checkbox" id="dropdown-sub" name="dropdown-sub" />
        
          </div>
        </div>
```

The expected behavior is for the droplist to expand when hovering over the "Import (CSV)" button. Currently, the droplist only expands when clicking the button.

I haven't received any error messages, I just haven't been able to get the droplist to expand on hover. I am using Angular, and my current version is 7.3.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change your `.dropdown:checked ~ .section-dropdown` selector with this:

`.dropdown:hover ~ .section-dropdown`

Hope this helped!

Comment: Thank you for your help! I changed the selector to ".dropdown:hover ~ .section-dropdown" as you suggested, and it did make the dropdown appear on hover. However, now I am facing an issue where the dropdown disappears immediately and I am unable to select any of the options. Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

Comment: @christianalvarez You'll want to change it to: `.dropdown:hover ~ .section-dropdown, .section-dropdown:hover` actually.